# Mahout killed error

Tags: hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine

I'm running a simple ItemSimilarityJob mahout job on a pseudo-distributed hadoop installation, and the process is stopped after a while with only message being killed:

```
12/06/05 21:04:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 33% reduce 8% 
12/06/05 21:05:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 36% reduce 8% 
12/06/05 21:05:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 39% reduce 8% 
Killed
```

Anybody have any idea why this would happen? I had several runs and this happens always, but at different stages.

SOLVED: SEEMS THAT IF MY COMPUTER GOES TO SLEEP IT KILLS ALL HADOOP JOBS.

Thanks,
Ilija

Comment: Shot into the dark: out of memory? Can you please post the tasklogs?

Comment: You could set your slowstart property to 1.0 to assist in diagnosing where the problem is (map or reduce side) - but as @ThomasJungblut says, the logs are the best place - post the log contents of what ever mapper of reducer task ended in the failed stat (not the killed state) - you should be able to find these in the job tracker Web UI page for your job

Comment: They are quite long? Is there some specific part I should look at? What should I expect to see if there is a memory issue?
The odd thing is that the job tracker says all jobs are successful?!

Comment: Are you sure these logs are for failed tasks? The Job Tracker has a Error column for the Failed map / reduce tasks - What does this list?

Comment: See pages 152 and 155 for what i'm referring to in the Job Tracker Web UI (the error column is shown on page 155) - http://books.google.com/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=job+tracker+screenshot+hadoop&source=bl&ots=IieyYnezWt&sig=YSbVkU-F0SnrsjyX6SBMToYBe-U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FnLOT73jJJKu6gHqob26DA&ved=0CF8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Screenshot%20of%20the%20job%20page&f=false

Comment: Yeap, I saw these files and no error reported in them. I think the problem was that I left my machine run and went away, and when it went to sleep (automatically after 40 mins) it just killed all the processes. I had another run, and I monitored the memory usage and the logs, and it finished with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your computer to sleep does not kill the processes. The problem is that when it wakes up, it appears that the workers have not reported back in a long time, and they are assumed to be stuck, so are killed. Yes, the 'fix' is of course to not let it go to sleep.